# Redirects on Plone

Tags: redirect, plone

What's the recommended way to do HTTP redirects on Plone using Python? What hooks are available? Can redirects managed through ZMI? My guess is that there is per site pre-traverse mechanism which allows you to check URL and intercept the request if it looks a redirect is needed.

We have some complex redirecting rules and it does not make sense to put them to Apache/NGINX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end this was the code I needed:

http://opensourcehacker.com/2011/08/03/python-based-http-redirect-rules-with-plone/

Unfortunately none of existing add-ons allowed to write redirect logic in Python in such simple manner.

Comment: 301: The blog post has been moved to http://opensourcehacker.com/2011/08/03/python-based-http-redirect-rules-with-plone/

Comment: fixed the link there (LONG LONG TEXT TEXT PLEASE ALLOW ME PRESS ADD COMMENT BUTTON NOW ALREADY

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can do something with: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.redirector. [RedirectionTool](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.RedirectionTool) uses this technology to allow TTW management of content that has been renamed in Plone. But I assume you could use it for whatever complex redirects you need to do in Python.

There is also:

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.fourohfour (middleware)

And:

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.redirect (which looks interesting.)

I agree it might be nice to have Plone handle redirects that are not strictly related to content (assuming this is what you mean by "complex redirecting")

Comment: plone.app.redirector kicks in as part of the page that is rendered when there's a 404...so it will only let you do redirects for paths that don't actually exist.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if http://plone.org/products/redirectiontool/ is the same as http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.RedirectionTool. the changelog and releasedates look different. it might be worth a try

Comment: They are the same; we need to make that more obvious somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not allowed to install anything new, you can use the underlying Zope to create a redirect via a Python script, see [details](http://cogumbreiro.blogspot.com/2009/04/redirecting-to-external-linkurl-in-zope.html).